# Mysql load null data

Tags: mysql

The document I want to upload is organized this way:

```
student@ubuntuM0151:~/PEC3$ head -5 Attributes.txt
GTEX-1117F-0003-SM-58Q7G    Blood   Whole Blood     
GTEX-1117F-0003-SM-5DWSB    Blood   Whole Blood     
GTEX-1117F-0003-SM-6WBT7    Blood   Whole Blood     
GTEX-1117F-0011-R10a-SM-AHZ7F   Brain   Brain - Frontal Cortex (BA9)    
GTEX-1117F-0011-R10b-SM-CYKQ8   Brain   Brain - Frontal Cortex (BA9)
```

I create a table to upload it to:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE attributes
    -> (sampID VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    -> muestra VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    -> cantidad FLOAT,
    -> PRIMARY KEY(muestra),
    -> FOREIGN KEY(sampID) REFERENCES agesex(SUBJID));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Attributes.txt' INTO TABLE attributes
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t" LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 65535 warnings (2.43 sec)
Records: 22951  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 22951  Warnings: 68853
```

I can't understand what is going on

Comment: Is agesex table populated before this load?

Comment: Do a select * from table_name; and check what is the value its printing. The txt file should be a backup I guess

Comment: Yes i poblated first the agesex table. The attributes table that i try to poblate has not accept my .txt